# Can't reference EF in ASP.NET 5 in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, resharper, asp.net-core

Can't reference EF in ASP.NET 5 in class library. I have no idea why. Visual Studio shows nothing. I'm trying to reference EF using ALT + ENTER (resharper shortcut). How can I solve my problem?

[image]

Comment: In addition - I've tried to reference EF manually, but "browse" button doesn't work for some reasons - http://screencast.com/t/RTRIywYr

Comment: Can you please share the `project.json` file?

Comment: All references are restored ? Don't u want use EF7 rather than 6 ?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of resharper or try disable resharper the problem could be caused by resharper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had any luck with Resharper pulling in NuGet packages for me just yet. I'm running the latest version too. I think this is because ASP.NET 5 is still in RC so full support isn't ready yet.

To address your problem:

Chances are your class library is targetting `net451` and `dotnet5.4`:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
        // etc
      }
    }
  }
```

However, this requires that your dependencies are also supporting `dotnet5.4`. I've found that a lot of packages have not moved to this new moniker yet. To get around it, I had to change my target to `dnxcore50` and get rid of `net451` (because I'm trying to target only .NET core and not the full .NET framework).

This explains why you're able to use EF in a console project - it uses `dnxcore50` by default :)

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
        // etc
      }
    }
  }
```

After this change, Resharper is able to see new packages I've added as dependencies and I can hit `Alt+Enter` to pull them in. Note: I do have to still add the packages manually in `project.json` or via the NuGet package manager. After I've done that Resharper plays nice.